# Elmah webconfig error 500 on Window2008r2 MVC2 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, elmah, sql-server-2008-r2

Just found out that i don't need httpHandler and the httpHandlers in the system.web and it still running

I have tried to integrate Elmah to my MVC2 Project and it works fine on my local, But when I upload it to the Web, which is window2008-r2. There i get "500 - Internal server error."

When i remove the httpHandler and the httpHandlers from the webconfig the the error is gone but elmah is not running.

Please help, how you I get it running on the 2008RC?

Here is what in my webconfig file:

```
  <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
  <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
  <section name="errorTweet" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorTweetSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

...
  
...

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
</httpModules>


<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/content/error.htm" />
```

...
  
...

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
</modules>


<handlers>
  <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

...

```
<security allowRemoteAccess="0" />

<!--
  quickest log method
  -->
<errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/Content/ErrorLog" />
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess you are using .net 4.0 on your 2008 box and this module is not compatible with .net 4

What I did is download the source files and compiled it as .net 4 and had no issues.  I am currently running Elmah on server 2008 using .net 4.0 and all is working just fine.

Just as a reference here is an excerpt from my web.config file

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah">
  <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
</sectionGroup>

<elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" />
  <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />    
</elmah>
<location path="elmah.axd">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <httpRuntime requestLengthDiskThreshold="256" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
  </system.web>
</location>

<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />      
</httpHandlers>

<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
</httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
 </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

whether or not httpHandlers is required in system.web is determined by whether you are on IIS6....It is better you keep both pieces as shown in the example by [odyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86524/odyth) so that it works fine for both IIS 6 and 7